# file_validate_size doesn't seem to work

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm currently learning how to make a custom module that creates a block with a textfield and upload field. So far so good, only thing is: Drupal doesn't seem to respect my file_validate_size value.

Here's my block_configure code:

```
            $form['file_link'] = array(
            '#type'         => 'managed_file',
            '#title'        => t('My upload field'),
            '#size'         => 60,
            '#description'  => t('Select a file.'),
            '#upload_location' => 'public://',
            '#default_value' => variable_get('file_link'),
            '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array(),
                                    'file_validate_size' => array(26214400)
                                    ),
        );
```

Most file_validate_size examples that i've found used bytes instead of megabytes. I don't know if this is a must? file_validate_extensions works perfectly though. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you are testing this as an Admin?

file_validate_size seems to be ignored for admins.

---

btw. if you want the size to be more readable you can write it like

```
'file_validate_size' => array( 25 * 1024 * 1024 )
```

this way you can tell at a glance that the limit is 25mb